# Nvidia driver not loaded on terminal only server

Tags: drivers

I have a terminal only server running in a VM (I am not the one who set it up).
I have access to a Tesla T4 GPU to run Machine Learning on.
The problem is, that even though the recommended nvidia 440 driver is installed, it seams to have issues communicating with the card:

```
user1@server1:~/log$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

But the card is correctly installed and even shows up in lspci:

```
02:02.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104GL [Tesla T4] (rev a1)
```

I tried reinstalling the driver and doing updates, but either way, the drivers doesn't seem to start.

Whats a good way to diagnose the issue?

Comment: Check `lspci -k` output — which driver is in use? See this for more details: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570618/131126

Comment: Oh yeah I should probaly answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I was working in a VM instead of on the actual server, which needed a propriatery VM driver for the virtualized GPU